# How can I print the "target" form the below image

Tags: python

**strong text**

code-->>

```
    for i in data_dict["design_state_data"]:
        print(i)
```

output-->>

```
      session_info
      target
      train
      metrics
      feature_handling
      feature_generation
      feature_reduction
      hyperparameters
      weighting_stratergy
      probability_calibration
      algorithms
```

How can i print the things inside the "target" from above

Comment: how is this java or json related? just random adding tags won't make your question a better one

Comment: I removed tags which doesn't match to problem in question.

Comment: do you mean `if i == 'target': print( data_dict["design_state_data"][i] )` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can print a matching string by doing the following:

```
for i in dictionary["key"]:
    if "string to match" in i.lower():
        print(i)
```

Alternatively, you can use regex:

```
import re
for i in dictionaty["key"]:
    if re.search("string to find", i):
        print(i)
```

The snippet above will print the item from the dict entry that contains the pattern "string to find"

There are variations, of course - you can read more about regex [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Edit: it has nothing to do with java. javascript, or machine learning